# How to perform a js function on every element with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, foreach, timezone

I have written a script that takes a time from a span set in this format: "October 29, 2020 9:00 am GMT" and swaps it for the computed date in the user's time zone.

The problem is that the code works only for the first span, I am new to javascript, and I cannot wrap my mind around how to create a foreach loop. Could someone help me adjust my script to be able to iterate through the provided html? Thanks in advance.

JavaScript:

```
var timestamp = document.getElementById('timestamp'),
        t         = new Date(timestamp.innerHTML),
        hours     = t.getHours(), 
        min       = t.getMinutes() + '', 
        pm        = false,
        months    = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    if(hours > 11){
       hours = hours - 12;
       pm = true;
    }

    if(hours == 0) hours = 12;
    if(min.length == 1) min = '0' + min;

    timestamp.innerHTML = months[t.getMonth()] + ' ' + t.getDate() + ', ' + t.getFullYear() + ' ' + hours + ':' + min + ' ' + (pm ? 'pm' : 'am') + ', ' + Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone + ' time';
```

HTML:

```
<span class="timestamp">October 29, 2020 9:00 am GMT</span><br>
<span class="timestamp">October 29, 2020 2:00 am GMT</span><br>
<span class="timestamp">October 29, 2020 4:00 am GMT</span><br>
<span class="timestamp">October 30, 2020 3:00 am GMT</span><br>
<span class="timestamp">October 28, 2020 7:00 am GMT</span><br>
<span class="timestamp">October 29, 2020 8:00 am GMT</span><br>
```

Comment: Title says class, but the code is `id`....So add a class, select all elements with the class, loop over the collection, run the code.

Comment: IDs have to be unique. Use a class, and then you can loop over all the elements with the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give all the elements a class of "timestamp" instead, as IDs are meant to be unique. You can then use `document.querySelectorAll` to obtain all the elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.timestamp').forEach(timestamp=>{
    let    t         = new Date(timestamp.innerHTML),
        hours     = t.getHours(), 
        min       = t.getMinutes() + '', 
        pm        = false,
        months    = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    if(hours > 11){
       hours = hours - 12;
       pm = true;
    }

    if(hours == 0) hours = 12;
    if(min.length == 1) min = '0' + min;

    timestamp.innerHTML = months[t.getMonth()] + ' ' + t.getDate() + ', ' + t.getFullYear() + ' ' + hours + ':' + min + ' ' + (pm ? 'pm' : 'am') + ', ' + Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone + ' time';
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just copied the code with id, I know they shouldn't be used multiple times, I have tried classes and getElementsByClassName(), but couldn't achieve what I wanted. Your Code works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The id had to be unique use timestamp better as classname. So you can get all of them with `document.getElementsByClassName`.

```js
let timestamps = document.getElementsByClassName('timestamp');
//console.log(timestamps, timestamps.length);
for (let i=0; i<timestamps.length; i++) {
    let    t         = new Date(timestamps[i].innerHTML),
        hours     = t.getHours(), 
        min       = t.getMinutes() + '', 
        pm        = false,
        months    = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    if(hours > 11){
       hours = hours - 12;
       pm = true;
    }

    if(hours == 0) hours = 12;
    if(min.length == 1) min = '0' + min;

    timestamps[i].innerHTML = months[t.getMonth()] + ' ' + t.getDate() + ', ' + t.getFullYear() + ' ' + hours + ':' + min + ' ' + (pm ? 'pm' : 'am') + ', ' + Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone + ' time';
}
```

```html
<span class="timestamp">October 29, 2020 9:00 am GMT</span><br>
<span class="timestamp">October 29, 2020 2:00 am GMT</span><br>
<span class="timestamp">October 29, 2020 4:00 am GMT</span><br>
<span class="timestamp">October 30, 2020 3:00 am GMT</span><br>
<span class="timestamp">October 28, 2020 7:00 am GMT</span><br>
<span class="timestamp">October 29, 2020 8:00 am GMT</span><br>
```